# Overloading the sails.log functions to include source filename where logs are coming from

Tags: sails.js

I want to overload the sails.log functions like info, debug, error, etc to include the path of the filename from where the logs are being printed. For example,

```
// api/controllers/UserController.js

module.exports =  {

  create: function (req, res) {
    // some operations
    sails.log.info("created a new user");
  }
}
```

The above log statement should prints

```
[api/controllers/UserController.js] info: created a new user
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer on gitter, https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails#

Posting the same here:

```
var winston = require('winston');

var getCaller = function ()
{
  var stack = getStack();
  stack.shift();
  var obj = stack[3];
  // Return caller's caller
  return obj.getFileName();
};

var getStack = function ()
{
  // Save original Error.prepareStackTrace
  var origPrepareStackTrace = Error.prepareStackTrace;

  // Override with function that just returns `stack`
  Error.prepareStackTrace = function (_, stack)
  {
    return stack;
  };

  // Create a new `Error`, which automatically gets `stack`
  var err = new Error();

  // Evaluate `err.stack`, which calls our new `Error.prepareStackTrace`
  var stack = err.stack;

  // Restore original `Error.prepareStackTrace`
  Error.prepareStackTrace = origPrepareStackTrace;

  // Remove superfluous function call on stack
  stack.shift(); // getStack --> Error

  return stack
};


var customLogger = new winston.Logger({
  transports: [
    new(winston.transports.File)({
      level: 'debug',
      filename: './logs/application.log'
    }),
    new (winston.transports.Console)({
      level: 'silly',
      colorize: true,
      timestamp: true
    })
  ]
});
customLogger.log = function(){
  var args = arguments;
  args[1] = getCaller()+" - "+args[1];

  winston.Logger.prototype.log.apply(this,args);
};
module.exports.log = {
  colors: false,
  custom: customLogger
};
```

Comment: this can also give you the function name from the stack

Answer (score 1):

Overriding SailsJS logger is convoluted. (https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2695)

I ended up using making my own logger. I simply created a log service.
`Log.js` in `api/services` folder.

In this file I

```
module.exports = {
    e:function(message){
        //do other stuffs here
        console.log(message);
    }
};
```

Then I can simply do this:

```
Log.e(message);
```

To get the name of the script file, you can use `__filename`. This returns entire path of the script/controller like this:

```
//console.log(__filename)

/Users/blab/Desktop/SM/api/controllers/BrandController.js
```

I hope this helps!